# There exists $L$ so that $\|x-\tilde{x}\|\leq \frac{1}{1-L}\cdot \sup_{z\in D} \|\phi(z) -\tilde{\phi}(z)\|\,$?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $x=\phi(x)$ and $\tilde{x}=\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})$ be two fixed point equations, which meet the requirements of the Banach fixed point theorem in $D\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Show, that there exists $0\leq L<1$, so that $$\|x-\tilde{x}\|\leq \frac{1}{1-L}\cdot  \underset{z\in D}{\sup} \|\phi(z) -\tilde{\phi}(z)\|.$$

I started with $\|x-\tilde{x}\|=\|\phi(x)-\tilde{\phi}(x)\|$ and my own idea is to work with the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde{\phi}$ have Lipschitz constant $L<1$. Then
$$
||x-\tilde{x}|| = ||\phi(x)-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})|| \le
||\phi(x)-\tilde{\phi}(x)|| + ||\tilde{\phi}(x)-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})||
$$
$$
\le (\sup_{z \in D} ||\phi(z)-\tilde{\phi}(z)||) + L||x-\tilde{x}||
$$
$$
\Rightarrow ||x-\tilde{x}|| \le \frac{1}{1-L}\sup_{z \in D} ||\phi(z)-\tilde{\phi}(z)||.
$$
This works even if $\phi$ is not a contraction, but has a fixed point $x$. The role of $\phi$ and $\tilde{\phi}$ can be interchanged. If $\phi$ is a contraction too, with constant $M<1$, say, then
$$
||x-\tilde{x}|| \le \frac{1}{1-\min\{L,M\}}\sup_{z \in D} ||\phi(z)-\tilde{\phi}(z)||.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I hope worth for you

$||x-\tilde{x}||=||\phi(x)-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})||\leq ||\phi(x)-\phi(\tilde{x})+\phi(\tilde{x})-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})+\tilde{\phi}(x)-\tilde{\phi}(x)|| \leq ||\phi(x)-\phi(\tilde{x})||+||\tilde{\phi}(x)-\tilde{\phi}(x)||+||\phi(\tilde{x})-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})||\leq L_1||x-\tilde{x}||+L_2||x-\tilde{x}||+||\phi(\tilde{x})-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})||$

then

$||x-\tilde{x}||(1-(L_1+L_2))\leq ||\phi(\tilde{x})-\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x})||\leq \sup ||\phi(z)-\tilde{\phi}(z)||$. Or equivalently

$$||x-\tilde{x}||\leq \frac{1}{1-L}\sup ||\phi(z)-\tilde{\phi}(z)||$$
with $L=L_1+L_2$, and $L_i$ is the constant contraction, $i=1,2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If $L_1, L_2$ are the contraction numbers of $\phi, \tilde{\phi}$, with  $L_1, L_2 \in [0,1)$, then it is possible, that $L=L_1+L_2$ is $\geq 1$ rigth? So you mybe divide by zero?

Comment: Good point, $0\leq L_i<1$ so, i believe that we need to minimize $L_1+L_2$ I mean, $1-\inf (L_1+L_2)||x-\tilde{x}||\leq ||x-\tilde{x}||(1-(L_1+L_2))$.

Comment: I believe that the $\inf$ exist because we are working in the real numbers, and by the conditions  we have $-1\leq 1-(L_1+L_2)\leq 1$, and define $L:=\inf(L_1+L_2)$